# How do I make the Vuetify.js "scroll off screen" toolbar work?

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm trying add the "scroll off screen" behavior to a toolbar

#### Here's the code:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MrONGb

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-content>
      <v-toolbar
      absolute
      color="teal lighten-3"
      dark
      scroll-off-screen
    >
      <v-toolbar-side-icon></v-toolbar-side-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title>Title</v-toolbar-title>
    </v-toolbar>
      <div style="height:1500px"></div>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

On the [example page](https://vuetifyjs.com/components/toolbars#example-11) It says:

> for this example there is special markup that will not be required in
> your application.

But what exactly I don't need? How do I make this code work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to add  `fixed` and `app` props on `v-toolbar` component (remove `absolute` prop)

Comment: Yeah, I understand, I added it so people can scroll down and see that it doesn't work, the toolbar isn't coming back until you scroll all the way back

Comment: @Un1 Updated, try

Comment: Ahh, it works now. Even without `app`, just added `fixed` and it works, thank you

Comment: I suggest that the answer is modified to remove "app", because it is not necessary.

Comment: @cosan Thanks for the input. I'm not sure if op modified the original codepen? Because I see it's `fixed` attribute there. I'm quite sure `app` was needed at the time of posting the question because that attribute is needed for some additional calculations when using some other components. Generally, I believe you would 
 want to include `app` on your main toolbar, sidebars and footer etc. Or perhaps its possible that something was changed in recent version of vuetify, I'm not sure because I didn't test this feature afterwords.

Answer (score 3):

you should add on toolbar prop: scroll-threshold="1" scroll-off-screen="true"